# route index for a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

What is the equivalent  index path for resources :topics if I were to write it out manually?
When I run rake routes with the resources line in the routes.rb file it shows.

```
    GET    /topics(.:format)         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"topics"}
```

I have tried a few things with no success, for example:

```
    get 'topics/index' #=> 'topics#index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the route says:

```
get "/topics" => "topics#index", :as => :topics
```

you can now use topics_path or topics_url